# Deploy Angular 6 to Heruko error

Tags: angular, heroku

I've just deployed a working Angular 6 app to Heroku.  It successfully built, but the page will not display.  The page says,

> An error occurred in the application and your page could not be
>   served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details

**Here is the log:**

```
 -----> Node.js app detected
-----> Creating runtime environment

       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  8.11.2
       engines.npm (package.json):   6.0.1

       Resolving node version 8.11.2...
       Downloading and installing node 8.11.2...
       Bootstrapping npm 6.0.1 (replacing 5.6.0)...
       npm 6.0.1 installed
-----> Restoring cache
       Skipping cache restore (not-found)
-----> Building dependencies
       Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)

       > uws@9.14.0 install /tmp/build_783e57ef498fd0603b4e43ee31371597/node_modules/uws
       > node-gyp rebuild > build_log.txt 2>&1 || exit 0


       > node-sass@4.9.0 install /tmp/build_783e57ef498fd0603b4e43ee31371597/node_modules/node-sass
       > node scripts/install.js

       Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.9.0/linux-x64-57_binding.node
       Download complete
       Binary saved to /tmp/build_783e57ef498fd0603b4e43ee31371597/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-57/binding.node
       Caching binary to /tmp/npmcache.TL2N2/node-sass/4.9.0/linux-x64-57_binding.node

       > node-sass@4.9.0 postinstall /tmp/build_783e57ef498fd0603b4e43ee31371597/node_modules/node-sass
       > node scripts/build.js

       Binary found at /tmp/build_783e57ef498fd0603b4e43ee31371597/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-57/binding.node
       Testing binary
       Binary is fine

       > @angular/cli@6.0.8 postinstall /tmp/build_783e57ef498fd0603b4e43ee31371597/node_modules/@angular/cli
       > node ./bin/ng-update-message.js


       > schoolsdropdown@0.0.0 postinstall /tmp/build_783e57ef498fd0603b4e43ee31371597
       > ng build --aot -prod

       Unknown option: '-p'
       added 1196 packages from 1369 contributors in 46.334s
       [!] 6 vulnerabilities found [22390 packages audited]
       Severity: 1 Low | 5 Moderate
       Run `npm audit` for more detail

-----> Caching build
       Clearing previous node cache
       Saving 2 cacheDirectories (default):
       - node_modules
       - bower_components (nothing to cache)
-----> Pruning devDependencies
       removed 844 packages in 12.953s
       [+] no known vulnerabilities found [9170 packages audited]

-----> Build succeeded!
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> (none)
       Default types for buildpack -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 46.5M
-----> Launching...
       Released v3
       https://schoolsdropdown.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

Is there something wrong with the -prod option?  How can this issue be resolved?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you did the wrong thing. What you want is to generate a production build using the Angular CLI (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build; `ng build`) and upload this production build/ output directory to Heroku (see http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/deploy-static-site-heroku for details).

Otherwise: You have to add `--prod` and not `-prod`

To summarize the chat: The problem was that the server.js file was in the src directory and not in the base directory but in the package.json was the base directory specified.

Comment: So create a dist file and deploy that only, correct?

Comment: Ok, I'm on it. Get back with you.

Comment: I'm getting the same error after deploying the dist files.

Comment: How do I display a log in this comment section?  It's too long.

Comment: <script src="https://gist.github.com/brohjoe1/1940e2c69f679157af6e1f6889a5e451.js"></script>

Comment: As a matter of fact I did.  Clairvoyant I see :-)  Will get the http address.

Comment: Oh so you did get to the log.  What does heroku logs say at the command line?   Not sure how to answer that.  Not sure what you mean.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172929/discussion-between-brohjoe-and-jonas-lochmann).